# Two types of Recursion in Python, one works, the other doesnt

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

Why does this code explode with **# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

```
import Tkinter as tk

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, counter_label(label))   

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and the below definition of counter_label doesn't?

```
def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        global counter
        counter += 1
        label.config(text=str(counter))
        label.after(1000, count)
    count()
```

Comment: You are both defining and using the function at the same time.  There is no base condition so you have infinite recursion in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
label.after(1000, counter_label(label))
```

This is exactly the same as this:

```
foo = counter_label(label)
label.after(1000, foo)
```

See the problem? You're immediately calling `counter_label` which immediately calls `counter_label` which immediately calls ...

When you use `after` you must give it a *reference* to a function. Additional arguments need to be given as additional arguments to `after`:

```
label.after(counter_label, label)
```

Comment: There you go! This is exactly it. I searched now and could not find the documentation entry for the after method, could you point me to the correct place?

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html is the best general tkinter reference I know of, other than going to the tcl/tk docs. For .after, see chapter 26 http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/univeral.html.

Answer (score 0):

in the first code snippet `label.after(1000, counter_label(label))` this code is gets called recursively without ever breaking out. For any recursion you need a base condition for the recursion to break out of it.

possible solution

```
def counter_label(label):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if counter == 10: # this is the base condition
        return counter; # anything that you want.
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, counter_label(label))
```

The second snippet is not recursion `label.after(1000, count)` you are just passing function reference to the lable.after as a second argument.

Comment: This does not correct the error in the .after method call.  See the last line in Bryan's answer.